# jupyter notebook ERROR PERMISSION DENIED:UNTITLED IPYNB

Tags: python-3.x, directory, jupyter-notebook, permission-denied

when i type jupyter notebook in command prompt i get it in a web browser but when i open a python-3 notebook its showing error

A dialoq box comes with the following things

```
Creating Notebook Failed
An error occurred while creating a new notebook.
Permission denied: Untitled ipynb
```

[screenshot of  the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE3bt.png)

this is what comes in the command propmt

```
[I 15:17:21.898 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
[W 15:17:22.435 NotebookApp] 403 POST /api/contents (::1): Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb
[W 15:17:22.437 NotebookApp] Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb
[W 15:17:22.462 NotebookApp] 403 POST /api/contents (::1) 565.45ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
```

also yesterday i had changed my deafault jupyter notebook  browser by generating conifg and made it to chrome but that wont be the problem rt?please give a detailed explanation?
also i heard it has something to do with directory name if that is the case tell me how to change it
thanks

Comment: Try to open jupyter notebook in a directory where you have editing permissions, or run the console as administrator.

Comment: i am not sure if this the reason why it worked but then i went to settings and disabled some security option for folder acess then i checked wheather the c drive prop>sec> gave acess to everything and restarted it worked ..!!

Comment: yah ik the administror option works but each time going to adminstrator mode is difficult..oh and by the way how do you open in a different directory 
i just dont understand anything about changing directories or opening it in diff onne seems so hard

Comment: The best way is just to move with the command prompt `cd <path>` before typing `jupyter notebook`